# Conditions within custom actions

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, custom-action, wix3.6

I recently separated our company installers in to two features (one enabled and one absent), to allow the user to select both, I've used UI_Mondo GUI to allow selection.

I've managed to get our custom action to work if the feature is selected:

```
<Custom Action="RestartIISForASPNet4" After="AspnetRegIIS"><![CDATA[(NOT INSTALLED) AND (&WebServiceFeature=3) AND NOT (!WebServiceFeature=3)]]></Custom
```

I tried but for some reason it's coming up with false (IMO, it can't as in the log the WixUI_InstallMode is set to InstallComplete.

```
<Custom Action="RestartIISForASPNet4" After="AspnetRegIIS"><![CDATA[((NOT INSTALLED) AND (&WebServiceFeature=3) AND NOT (!WebServiceFeature=3)) OR WixUI_InstallMode = "InstallComplete"]]></Custom>
```

Anybody have any ideas what I'm missing, it's probably really obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WixUI_InstallMode is a [private property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370851%28VS.85%29.aspx). This means it uses its default value during InstallExecuteSequence (when your custom action runs).

A solution is to use custom action to save its value in a [public property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370912%28VS.85%29.aspx). You can then use that public property in your condition.

Public properties don't have lowercase letters in their names.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds enlightening! Do you have an example of using that kind of custom action by any chance? Or a page to learn from, never done that before.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_setproperty.htm